# Type checking when parsing

Tags: c++, templates, types

When parsing a file, I want to introduce type checking. Decided to create a list of types with indexing

```
template<typename... Elements>
class TypeList {};

using MyTypes = TypeList<int, double, float/* etc */>;

/********/
template<typename List>
class FrontT;

template<typename Head, typename... Tail >
class FrontT<TypeList<Head, Tail...>>
{
public:
    using Type = Head;
};

template<typename List>
using Front = typename FrontT<List>::Type;

/*********/
template<typename List>
class PopFrontT;

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
class PopFrontT<TypeList<Head, Tail...>>
{
public:
    using Type = TypeList<Tail... >;
};
template<typename List >
using PopFront = typename PopFrontT<List > ::Type;

/********/
template<typename List, unsigned N >
class GetNthType : public GetNthType <PopFront<List>, N - 1 >{};

template<typename List>
class GetNthType<List, 0> : public FrontT<List>{};

template<typename List, unsigned N>
using GetNthTypeT = typename GetNthType<List, N >::Type;
```

Next, I try to write the following function 'my_common_with', but it doesn't compile. How to select an compile-time index from an input string?

```
static constexpr unsigned INT_ID    = 0;
static constexpr unsigned DOUBLE_ID = 1;
static constexpr unsigned FLOAT_ID  = 2;

constexpr unsigned get_by_string(const std::string& s1)
{
    if (s1 == "int")
        return INT_T;
    if (s1 == "double")
        return DOUBLE_ID;
    if (s1 == "float")
        return FLOAT_ID;
    return INT_T;
}

constexpr bool my_common_with(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    return std::common_with<
        GetNthTypeT<MyTypes, get_by_string(s1)>,
        GetNthTypeT<MyTypes, get_by_string(s2)>
    >;
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Looks a bit like you are trying to re-implement [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) – wouldn't you rather want to use that one?

Comment: This question feels very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What is the actual and underlying problem this code is supposed to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When parsing expressions from a file, I want to check that these expressions are type correct. For example, input "c = fun(a/b)" and I know all type.